# No matching function for call to 'std::vector<datos>::push_back(std::string&)' leer desde fichero

Tags: c++

Hola la cosa es que tengo que leer datos desde un fichero y guardarlos en vectores, estos datos son 2 string y 38 int. Para cada uno hay asignado un vector de tipo datos que es la tupla que he definido con los dos string y los 38 int. Pero tengo problemas a la hora de entrar los datos dedse el fichero y cargarlos alfinal del vector, alguien hecha una mano. Gracias.

```
struct  datos{
         string pais, codigo;
         int a80, a81, a82, a83, a84, a85, a86, a87, a88, a89, a90, a91;
        };
int main(){
vector<datos> country, code, an80, an81, an82, an83, an84, an85, an86, an87, an88, an89, an90, an91;
datos resi, n_resi;
ifstream fin("prueba.txt");

while (fin>>resi.pais>>resi.codigo>>resi.a80>>resi.a81>>resi.a82>>resi.a83>>resi.a84>>resi.a85>>resi.a86>>resi.a87>>resi.a89>>resi.a90>>resi.a91){
country.push_back(resi.pais);
code.push_back(resi.codigo);
an80.push_back(resi.a80);
an81.push_back(resi.a81);
an82.push_back(resi.a82);
an83.push_back(resi.a83);
an84.push_back(resi.a84);
an85.push_back(resi.a85);
an86.push_back(resi.a86);
an87.push_back(resi.a87);
an88.push_back(resi.a88);
an89.push_back(resi.a89);
an90.push_back(resi.a90);
an91.push_back(resi.a91);

} // fin del while



    for (int i=0; i<pais.size();i++){//i<numero de paises+1
    cout<<country[i]<<code[i]<<an80[i]<<an81[i]<<an82[i]<<an83[i]<<an84[i]<<an85[i]<<an87[i]<<an88[i]<<an89[i]<<an90[i]<<an91[i];
    cout<<"Fin"<<endl;
```

} // fin del for
} // fin del main
'''

```
       int main(){
vector<datos> country, code, an80, an81, an82, an83, an84, an85, an86, an87, an88, an89, an90, an91;
datos resi, n_resi;
ifstream fin("prueba.txt");

while (fin>>resi.pais>>resi.codigo>>resi.a80>>resi.a81>>resi.a82>>resi.a83>>resi.a84>>resi.a85>>resi.a86>>resi.a87>>resi.a89>>resi.a90>>resi.a91){
country.push_back(resi.pais);
code.push_back(resi.codigo);
an80.push_back(resi.a80);
an81.push_back(resi.a81);
an82.push_back(resi.a82);
an83.push_back(resi.a83);
an84.push_back(resi.a84);
an85.push_back(resi.a85);
an86.push_back(resi.a86);
an87.push_back(resi.a87);
an88.push_back(resi.a88);
an89.push_back(resi.a89);
an90.push_back(resi.a90);
an91.push_back(resi.a91);

} // fin del while



    for (int i=0; i<pais.size();i++){//i<numero de paises+1
    cout<<country[i]<<code[i]<<an80[i]<<an81[i]<<an82[i]<<an83[i]<<an84[i]<<an85[i]<<an87[i]<<an88[i]<<an89[i]<<an90[i]<<an91[i];
    cout<<"Fin"<<endl;
```

} // fin del for
} // fin del main

Comment: Hmm.  Parece que ya se respondió esta pregunta aquí:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363591/mostrar-vector-dentro-de-una-tupla

Answer (score 0):

En principio yo recomendaria cambiar tus 12 variables `int` a un arreglo de 12 esapcio `int[12]`, de modo que es más sencillo de entender el codigo. también recuerda que los vectores son arreglos de dimensión variable, en tu codigo haces vectores de tipo `datos`, entonces a la hora de hacer el `push_back` le das como parametro un campo de la estructura, `string o int`, por eso marca el error, debes pasarle como parametro una estructura de tipo `datos`.

```
typedef struct d{
    string country, code;
    int a80, a81, a82, a83, a84, a85, a86, a87, a88, a89, a90, a91;
}datos;


int main(){
    vector<datos> temp;
    datos resi;
    ifstream fin("prueba.txt");

    while(!fin.eof()){
        fin>>resi.country>>resi.codigo>>resi.a80>>resi.a81>>resi.a82>>resi.a83>>resi.a84>>resi.a85>>resi.a86>>resi.a87>>resi.a89>>resi.a90>>resi.a91;
        temp.push_back(resi);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<temp.size();i++){
        cout<<temp[i].country<<temp[i].code<<temp[i].an80<<temp[i].an81<<temp[i].an82<<temp[i].an83<<temp[i].an84<<temp[i].an85<<temp[i].an87<<temp[i].an88<<temp[i].an89<<temp[i].an90<<temp[i].an91;
        cout<<"Fin"<<endl;
    }
```

En este código modifico un poco el tuyo con las caracteristicas que comente antes, de modo que solo se tiene un vector de `datos`, el cual se llena conforme lee el archivo, llena una estructura y la agrega al vector. Al final solo itera en el vector, de modo que tenemos acceso a todas las estructuras que agregamos antes, el vector es un arreglo así que solo iteramos en el y usamos el `.atributo` para acceder al campo de la estructura que esta en la posición `i` del vector.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Disculpa si te sigo molestando que soy nuevo en C++, poque solo entrenas una vez: