# Mostrar vector dentro de una tupla

Tags: c++, array, tuplas

tengo un par de dudas para mostrar los numeros que tengo dentro del vector que pertenece a esta tupla. Mi fichero tiene dos clumnas de strings que son nombres de paises y codigos y despues otras 38 mas que son numero enteros. Cuando intento mostrar los datos de dentro de los vectores solo me sale el nombre y el codigo del primer pais y los 38 enteros pero a la hora de sacar el segundo pais y codigo sale un 0seguido del nombre del pais y los 38 numeros son los del primero.Adjunto foto del fichero,me gustaria que el cout fuera identico al fichero de texto. Gracias.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    struct datos{
    string pais, codigo;
    vector <int> anys;
    };

    int main (){
    vector<datos> resi;
    datos papo;
    ifstream fin("pru.txt");
    int any, i=0; // vable que llegeix els anys desde el fitxer

    while(fin>>papo.pais>>papo.codigo){
      while(i<38){
         fin>>any;
          papo.anys.push_back(any);
          i++;
      }
        resi.push_back(papo);

   } // fin del whilel
   for (int k=0; k<7;k++){
    cout <<resi[k].pais<<resi[k].codigo<< endl;
    for (int t=0; t<38; t++){
        cout << resi[k].anys[t]<<" ";
   }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No pones `i` a cero al acabar el bucle:

```
while(fin>>papo.pais>>papo.codigo){
  while(i<38){
     fin>>any;
      papo.anys.push_back(any);
      i++;
  }
    resi.push_back(papo);
    i = 0; // <---- Falta esto.
}
```

Por norma general, usa el bucle `while` cuando no sepas cuantos ciclos tienes que hacer y el bucle `for` en caso contrario. Por lo tanto:

```
while(fin >> papo.pais >> papo.codigo){
    for (int i = 0; i != 38; ++i)
        fin>>any;
        papo.anys.push_back(any);
    }
    resi.push_back(papo);
}
```

Por cierto, no estás usando ninguna tupla (al contrario de lo que indica el título).

#### Propuesta.

Haz que tu objeto de datos sobrecargue el operador de lectura de flujo de entrada, por cierto, el objeto contiene información de UN solo país, no tiene sentido que su nombre sea en plural:

```
struct dato{
    std::string pais, codigo;
    std::vector<int> anys;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, dato &d) {
    i >> d.pais >> d.codigo;
    d.anys.resize(38);
    for (int columna = 0; columna != 38; ++columna)
        i >> d.anys[columna];
    return i;
}
```

Aprovecha para sobrecargar también el operador de escritura de datos:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const dato &d) {
    o << d.pais << ' ' << d.codigo;
    for (const auto &anyo : d.anys)
        o << anyo;
    return o;
}
```

De esta manera, tu código podría quedar así:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<dato> datos;

    if (std::ifstream fin{"pru.txt"})
    {
        dato d;
        fin >> d;
        datos.push_back(d);
    }

    for (const auto &d : datos)
        std::cout << d << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una manera elegante de resolver tu problema usando:

1. Operador de inserción (>>)
2. Algoritmo `std::copy`
3. Iteradores de entrada sobre flujos (`std::istream_iterator`).

Básicamente, tu código de lectura para cargar desde el archivo/fichero (decimos archivo en México :-)) se verá así:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<datos>(fin),  // iterador inicial
           std::istream_iterator<datos>(),    // iterador final (iterador singular)
           std::back_inserter(resi));         // inserta con push_back en resi
```

**Desglosando**:
Los iteradores sobre un flujo de entrada leen tipos T (en tu caso, la estructura `datos` hasta que se tope con el fin del flujo, que en el caso de un archivo será EOF.  Por lo tanto, necesitas dos iteradores: el de inicio y el final.  El de inicio lo puedes construir con el ifstream fin que ya tienes, o puedes utilizar `std::istream_iterator<datos>{ifstream{"pru.txt"}}`.  El del final utiliza los que se conoce como un iterador singular, que es una técnica para detectar el final se alguna secuencia--ya que cuando el primer iterador llega al fin del flujo/archivo, al comparar con el otro iterador, se comparan como iguales y el bucle o algoritmo termina. Necesitas incluir el archivo de encabezado/la cabecera `iterator`.

Para poder leer el tipo T, tal tipo debe tener o bien una función miembro que lea el tipo T, o una función no-miembro declarada como `friend` del tipo T (para acceder a los datos miembros no-públicos de T.  @PaperBirdMaster ya proporcionó un par de funciones para leer y escribir de/a flujos. Como todos los datos miembro son públicos, no se necesita declarar las funciones como `friend`.

Para poder insertar en el vector, necesitas un iterador especial llamado `back_inserter`, que cuando se llama, efectivamente llama a la función `push_back` del contenedor que pasaste en su constructor.

Para terminar, puedes usar el algoritmo `std::copy`.  El código para la parte de la lectura--utilizando los operadores >> y << de @PaperBirdMaster:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct datos {
    string pais, codigo;
    vector <int> anys;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& i, datos& d) {
    i >> d.pais >> d.codigo;
    d.anys.resize(38); // usa una constante en lugar de números mágicos
    for (int columna = 0; columna != 38; ++columna)
        i >> d.anys[columna];
    return i;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const datos& d) {
    o << d.pais << ' ' << d.codigo;
    for (const auto& anyo : d.anys)
        o << anyo;
    return o;
}


int main() {
    vector<datos> resi;
    datos papo;
    ifstream fin("pru.txt");

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<datos>(fin),
              std::istream_iterator<datos>(),
              std::back_inserter(resi));

}
```

El resto que quede de tarea :-).

**Pista**: Existe `ostream_iterator` y puedes copiar a un flujo de salida.